# Codeigniter not passing arrays or objects from controller to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, view

I have a problem with codeigniter's passing arrays and objects from controller to view.
Data is pulled from database in model and is visible in the controller (var_dump shows that data is there), but somehow, it is not passing to view.

Here is the controller code

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->load->model('post_model');

    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_all_posts();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

After this, on the view side $posts is unavailable. 
var_dump($posts); responds as Undefined variable: posts

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: please paste var_drump of $data['posts']

Comment: You are loading the view twice, once before the variable gets defined and once after the variable gets defined.

Comment: Ryan, you are right, problem is solved. How can i donate?

Comment: I left an answer or you can give it to Programming Student. I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the view twice, once before the variable gets defined and once after the variable gets defined.

Your code should look as follows:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('post_model');

    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_all_posts();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the view twice.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message'); // first time, here you are not sending any data
    $this->load->model('post_model');
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_all_posts();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);// second time
}
```